# Is there a function in Drupal Commerce which could perform a buying of a product programmatically?

Tags: 7, commerce

For example, I need to perform a purchase of some product by some user programmatically. That as, I call a function having passed papameters such as user_id, product_id and price. By the way, this price can be different from price assigned before.

And after execution of the function it would be considered that the user has bought the product.

For example, a e-shop sells access to some files and salesman wants to gift access to some file to some user upon the occurrence of some event. for example, user's birthday. And in this case this function with params user_id, product_id and price=0 could solve the problem.

Or these problems are solved by another way ?

Comment: Just a guess (so I'm not posting this as answer): the function you're looking for might be `commerce_order_save()`. It only accepts one argument: an order entity object. You would have to prepare that order object yourself and insert the values like the user ID, a line item containing the product ID, and the fact that is considered to be fully paid for.

Comment: That is, I have to create Commerce Line item entity (or items entities), next to create a Commerce Order entity and finally to call commerce_order_save with the commerce order entity as a parameter ?

Isn't there a simpler solution like I described above ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I don't know all ins and outs of Commerce, but I'm afraid there is no simpler solution. Commerce was not designed to be simple, it was designed to be flexible.